# Sum of non-trivial divisors of number equals number itself

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisor-sum

> Is there a number $n$ such that it equals the sum of its non-trivial divisors (i.e. all of its divisors except 1 and $n$)? If yes, what are such numbers called and what are some examples of them?

I have not found any answers on the internet.

Comment: do you mean the perfect numbers?

Comment: I was going to say that, but I note that OP excludes 1 from his definition.

Comment: have you tried a computer search?

Comment: @lulu I'm not a programmer.

Comment: even so.  Shouldn't be hard to check up to $100$, at least.  Easy to see that $pq$, product of distinct primes can't work, for example.  Maybe the product of three primes.

Comment: Note:  excluding squares, the sum of divisors is always even.  If your number were even (and not a square) then it is impossible:  the divisor sum is even and you subtract $1$ and $n$ you get an odd number.  So you can exclude all the even non-squares immediately.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Congratulations, you've walked into an open problem. Any number $n$ would satisfy $\sigma(n)-n-1=n$ or $\sigma(n)=2n+1$, i.e. have an abundance of 1. But a note on the relevant OEIS entry, [A033880](https://oeis.org/A033880) (abundance of $n$), states:

> For no known $n$ is $a(n)=1$. If there is such an $n$ it must be greater than $10^{35}$ and have seven or more distinct prime factors (Hagis and Cohen 1982). - Jonathan Vos Post, May 01 2011

These are called quasiperfect numbers.